# CSS Table within Table, Space between rows (not columns)

Tags: css, html-table

I'm having what seems to be a basic CSS issue.

I have a table within a table, and the imbedded table is there to contain a sliced image to support a rollover graphic change.

The second row of the imbedded table is getting a space between the first row and itself.

Here is the HTML Markup:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th class="appResourceHead text14px textBold">Parametric Search</th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td class="appResourceBodyNoPad text12px">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td> <a href="http://web.centralsemi.com/paraSearch/parametricSearch_v1_1.php">
              <img src="http://www.centralsemi.com/centralSemi/images/Parametric_Search_01.png" width="163" height="132" style="border-style: none;" />
            </a>

          </td>
          <td> <a href="http://web.centralsemi.com/paraSearch/parametricSearch_v1_1.php">
              <img src="http://www.centralsemi.com/centralSemi/images/Parametric_Search_02.png" width="67" height="132" style="border-style: none;" />
            </a>

          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <a href="http://web.centralsemi.com/paraSearch/parametricSearch_v1_1.php">
              <img src="http://www.centralsemi.com/centralSemi/images/Parametric_Search_03.png" width="163" height="48" style="border-style: none;" />
            </a>

          </td>
          <td><a href="http://web.centralsemi.com/paraSearch/parametricSearch_v1_1.php">
              <img src="/centralSemi/images/Parametric_Search_04.png" rel="/centralSemi/images/Parametric_Search_Down_04.png" class="rollover" width="67" height="48" style="border-style: none;" />
              </a>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following jsfiddle to show you my markup in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/5bZtz/

When looking at the table in Firefox and Chrome I don’t have the space, but in IE the space is shown like you can see in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: A) The space is not between the rows. It's inside the anchors. You can't have space between rows in HTML. B) I see the spacing too in Opera. C) Why do you need a table at all? You could get rid of 98% of your markup and still achieve the same. D) ["The text-rendering property is an SVG property that is not defined in any CSS standard."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add below code in your css,

```
    td {
    line-height:0;
    }
```

I update your fiddle here. Kindly see it works ! http://jsfiddle.net/5bZtz/1/

Good Luck ..)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be was relativly simple. Never knew that line-height can throw off something like this.

Comment: Nice! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Add to `<a href="http://web.centralsemi.com/paraSearch/parametricSearch_v1_1.php"><img ... /></a>` css properties: `display:block;` and `height:132px;`